# Comparing an integer with an element of an integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to programming, i searched but none of the questions were exact answer of my question or the language wasn't c. I'm programming something else but i just wanted to simplify for myself to understand better. So my question is, how can i see Done when i enter a number that is in the list ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
int c[ ] = {0, 1, 2};
int x;

scanf("%d", &x);

if( *c == x )
    printf("Done");
else    
    printf("Fail");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Various answers use `3`.  Code could use `#define N (sizeof c/sizeof c[0])` so the list `c[]` can change size without re-coding the `3`.  This helps avoid "magic numbers".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cycle over the elements in the array(e.g. using `for`) and compare each entry with the value of x.

Comment: The problem is I want to write a letter only once and my solution was storing letters in array and than comparing the input with the stored arrays list so if i use 'for' i won't be able to compare the other same letters

Comment: @user3091393 This is what `break;` inside a `for`loop is used for. Look it up and when you're on it look for `continue;` too

Answer (score 0):

Check against each value in the list; if you see a match, declare victory and return.

If no match was found, then print "Fail".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
  int c[ ] = {0, 1, 2};
  int x;
  int i;

  scanf("%d", &x);

  for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
  {
    if ( c[i] == x )
    {
      printf("Done");
      return 0;
    }
  }

  printf("Fail");

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
int c[ ] = {0, 1, 2};
int x, i;

scanf("%d", &x);

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    if( c[i] == x )
    {
        printf("Done");
        break;
    } 

if(i==3)
    printf("Fail");

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a (not so tidy) way of doing this.

In C, you reference each element of an array using the array name followed by square brackets and an integer value (which can be a constant, a variable, a function call or anything else that provides an integer).

By using a for loop and using the loop variable to reference the array, you are checking element 0, followed by element 1, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c[] = {0, 1, 2};
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        if(c[i] == x )
            printf("Done");
        else
            printf("Fail");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In actual code, you wouldn't use "i<3" in the for loop just because it means that the loop wouldn't scale with the size of the array.

As noted by Paul Roub in the comments, this would display "FailFailDone" if you entered 2. In the case that you only wanted to show the value when it succeeded, you could either use "break" or "return(0)" after the first print statement. Example below.

```
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        if(c[i] == x )
        {
            printf("Done");
            return(0);
        }
    }
    printf("Fail");
```

Further edits made after interjay's comment. Now the code will only print "Done" if the number has been found, otherwise it will print "Fail".

Comment: That's going to print "Fail" for each non-matching item in the list, even if another matches.

Comment: I assumed that that was how they wanted it output so that they could see if it was matching or not, but I'll update it to make a point of it.

Comment: Your "fixed" version will only compare the first array element.

Comment: Fair point, didn't notice that the first time around. Editing again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int c[] = {0, 1, 2};
int x;

scanf("%d", &x);
int i=0;
while(c[i]!=x && i<3)
{
    i++;
}
if(i==3)
{
    printf("FAIL");
}
else
{
    printf("DONE");
}
return 0;
}
```